# Authentication problems, multiple users, git, github, terminal, osx

Tags: git, macos, authentication, github, credentials

I cannot push changes to my remote repository on github. I get this authentication error:

> remote: Permission to newuser/repository.git denied to olduser.
>   fatal: unable to access 
>   'https://github.com/newuser/repository.git/': The requested URL 
>   returned error: 403

(I replaced my actual username and repository)
I'm migrating a project to a new account and git is trying to authenticate with my old user credentials.
I unset the global 'user.name' (which was 'olduser') and set a local 'user.name' to 'newuser'. Now my configs look like this:

```
core.editor=Sublime
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean %f
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge %f
filter.lfs.required=true
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/newuser/repository.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
user.name=newuser
```

I also had tried to add a osxkeychain as credential helper, but I don't think that addresses anything. I don't know how to fix this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git config user.name` has nothing to do with authentication. It only help setting the right author/committer when making commits.

[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) can help, but you need to make sure that git will use the new username when pushing.

A trick to ensure that is to embed that new username into the push url:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin https://username@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Then try again pushing.